# Delphi XE4 detect an item switch between TListGroups

Tags: delphi, listview, delphi-xe4

I've been using Delphi XE4 for a week now and I've just discovered the new `TListGroups` feature. It's easy to set the `TlistItem`'s `GroupID` to switch/move between the groups with ease. Now, I would like to have a procedure that calls as soon as a `TListItem` LEAVES a Group and/or as soon as a `TlistItem` ENTERS a Group. I'm looking for something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1On(Before/After)ListGroupEnter(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 // Do some stuff here like...
 // AllowedToDraw := TRUE/FALSE
 // I/O Code...
 // etc...
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1On(Before/After)ListGroupLeave(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 // Do some stuff here like...
 // This might be replaceable with OnDeletion...
 // I/O Code...
end;
```

The main problem here is to detect the switch between various groups if you set the `GroupID` property.
So is there anything to detect the switch as soon as you change/set the `GroupID` property?

Comment: It would need to intercept `TListItem.SetGroupID` setter. Better make your own helper function and set the `GroupID` to the items from there.

Comment: I don't exactly know how it treats the group switch tho. Does it delete the item completely and then re-adds it to another group?

Comment: The `GroupID` setter just sets the `iGroupId` member of the [`LVITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774760(v=vs.85).aspx) structure which represents the item. The rest is upon system.

Comment: So I guess there is no easy way to do that.

Comment: No, there's not much to choose from here. You can intercept that setter, or make a function (or e.g. a method to the intercepted `TListItem` class). This function will be able to fire your own event and set the `GroupID` of the item.

Comment: Thank you. If you find time and will to give me an example, it would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TListItem.GroupID` property setter sends a `LVM_SETITEM` message to the `TListView's` HWND.  You can subclass the `TListView` and intercept that message before the `TListView` processes it, eg:

```
const
  APPWM_LISTVIEW_CHECKGROUP = WM_APP + 100;

var
  PrevLVWndProc: TWndMethod = nil;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrevLVWndProc := ListView1.WindowProc;
  ListView1.WindowProc := LVWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ListView1.WindowProc := PrevLVWndProc;
end;

procedure TForm1.LVWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
var
  LVItem: PLVItem;
  ListItem: TListItem;
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    LVM_SETITEM:
    begin
      LVItem := PLVItem(Message.LParam);
      if (LVItem^.mask and LVIF_GROUPID) <> 0 then
      begin
        ListItem := ListView1.Items[LVItem.iItem];

        if ListItem.GroupID <> LVItem.iGroupID then
        begin
          if ListItem.GroupID >= 0 then
            ListView1GroupLeave(ListView1, ListItem);

          PrevLVWndProc(Message);

          // this gives the TListItem time to actually update itself
          PostMessage(ListView1.Handle, APPWM_LISTVIEW_CHECKGROUP, 0, LVItem.iItem);

          Exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    APPWM_LISTVIEW_CHECKGROUP:
    begin
      ListItem := ListView1.Items[Message.LParam];
      if ListItem.GroupID >= 0 then
        ListView1GroupEnter(ListView1, ListItem);
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  PrevLVWndProc(Message);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1GroupLeave(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  // Item is about to leave from its current GroupID ...
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1GroupEnter(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
  // Item has entered into its current GroupID ...
end;
```

Comment: Works. Thank you very much. They need to add this in future embarcadero products.